# How sound waves are generated in IC engine?

Tags: acoustics, combustion

I have found the source of sound in the IC engine as aerodynamic, combustion, and mechanical. But I want to know which among the 3 is the major source. Also what happens during the combustion of fuel in the cylinder and how sound waves are generated and propagated in the cylinder after combustion.

Answer (score 1):

The most significant sound source is related to *combustion*, when the exhaust valve opens and the hot gases explode out of the cylinder and into the exhaust pipe(s). Here is how to demonstrate this:

Imagine you are riding on a high-performance motorcycle, like a 4-cylinder, 1000cc Suzuki. You twist open the throttle and take off at full power, revving the engine all the way up to 10,000RPM, at which the engine will be VERY noisy- with the majority of the noise coming from the exhaust pipes. Then you close the fuel valve completely- and now there's no combustion occurring in the cylinders, and the noise output of the engine falls off dramatically. As the engine is slowing down, the noises you hear then are created by the valve mechanism, the cam drive chain, the gear teeth in the transmission and the shaking of the engine block caused by imperfect dynamic balance.

As the engine slows down to 5000RPM, you leave the fuel off and then open the throttle all the way once again. Now you hear the pulsations of the air flow in the carburetors being radiated outwards through the air cleaner, which is a sound you can turn on and off by opening and closing the throttle.

Then, with the throttle closed and the fuel off, you pull in the clutch so the engine comes to a halt while the motorcycle is still coasting. The noises you now hear are coming from the gears in the transmission and the final drive.

Then you click the transmission into neutral while still holding in the clutch. The sounds you then hear are coming from the drive chain or the shaft-drive gears.

Experiments like this will allow you to determine how much noise is coming from.

Comment: Thanks, Nielsen for the information. But if the major source of sound in the Ic engine is not the combustion but is the hot gases exploding out of the cylinder and into the exhaust pipe(s). Then can you please explain how  loud sound is generated by the combustion of firecrackers